# Default path in a path with children

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I am using angular 6 and for the cms of the app I have the following paths set up in the `app.modules.ts` file.

```
{ path: 'cms', component: CmsComponentComponent, children: [
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'educate', component: EducateComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] }
]},
```

I would like to have a default `cms`, so if I type `app/cms` I would got to Register.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you only have to add a redirect route like this:

```
{ path: 'cms', component: CmsComponentComponent, children: [
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    ...
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/register', pathMatch: 'full' }
]},
```